# Azure API management with URL Template Parameters and Function Backend

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I'm trying to setup an endpoint on Azure API Management with url parameters that routes to an Azure function.

EG: `GET my-api-gateway.azure-api.net.com/product/{productId}`

My inbound policies just set the backend and move the template param to a query param.

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-query-parameter name="productId" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["productId"])</value>
        </set-query-parameter>
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="product-function" />
    </inbound>
```

However, when I call `my-api-gateway.azure-api.net.com/product/123`, the `/123` also gets passed to the backend function url

`https://my-function.azurewebsites.net/api/product-function/123?productId=123`

which results in a 404.

Is there someway to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

One way to resolve is to add route to the backend as you have shown in your own answer. However, if you cannot do that, then answer to your original question is to introduce a uri rewrite:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <rewrite-uri template="/product-function" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
    <set-query-parameter name="productId" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["productId"])</value>
    </set-query-parameter>
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="product-function" />
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I also needed to setup `routes` my the function itself.

In my `function.json`, I added the following to match my API and now it works:

```
 "route": "product-function/{productId?}"
```